# pass multiple values from a function defined in one file to another file using c

Tags: c

I have a task get multiple values from one function defined in one.c file to other function defined in two.c file.

Please find below code snippet from both the files and kindly help to access the values from one.c file into two.c file.

file one.c:

```
void GetABFWversion(uint8_t* fwcommand, uint8_t* fwaction, uint16_t* fwvalue)             
{
    uint16_t FW_slot=SdusAutoDetectSlotForNewFirmware();

    char MyCopy[10];  
    strcpy (MyCopy, BrakeBoardInfo.firmwareVersion);
    char MyCopy1[10];
    for (int k=0; k<9; k++)
    {
      int l=1;
      MyCopy1[k] = MyCopy[k+l]; 
    }

    char FWversion_AB[10] = {0};
    int z = 0;
    for(int x=6;x<10;x++)
    {
      FWversion_AB[z] = MyCopy1[x];
      z++;
    }

    char res=0;

    uint16_t val = atoi(FWversion_AB);
    //res = proto485OnlyWrite(0x09,0x02,0x00,val);
    printf("\n");
    printf("FW version is sent to Arduino!!!   ");
    RESULT = 1;
    *fwcommand = 0x02;
    *fwaction = 0x00;
    *fwvalue = val;
}
```

file two.c:

```
int16_t driver485Read (uint8_t *buffer, const uint16_t length)
{
  char head[20];  
  const char *format="KL%02x:";
  int16_t wait_loop_cnt=0;
  static uint32_t totalBytes = 0;
  static uint32_t respNo = 0;

  GPIO_ClearValue(PMAP_GPIO_PORT_DIR_RS485, PMAP_GPIO_PIN_DIR_RS485);             

  UartRxFlush(UARW_UART_INDEX_RS485); /
  respNo++;

  int counter = 0; 

  do
  {
    OSTimeDly(2);

    int8_t newBytesRcv = UartReceive(UARW_UART_INDEX_RS485,
                                     (uint8_t*)&(buffer[counter]), length-counter);
    totalBytes += newBytesRcv;
    counter = totalBytes;
  }
  while (/*wait_loop_cnt++<= MAX_WAIT_LOOP &&*/ counter < length);  
  totalBytes = 0;

  uint8_t i = 0;
  format="OK%02x:";

  printf("Byte received........");
  int FWmsg[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x32,0x32,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x31};
  int arduinodata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};  

  for (i=0; i<9;i++)
  {
  printf("%d  ",buffer[i]);
  arduinodata[i] = buffer[i];
  }

  if(compareArray(FWmsg,arduinodata,7)==0)
  {  
    printf("Arrays have same elements.\n");
    printArray(FWmsg,9);

  char res = 0;

  uint8_t fwc, fwa;
  uint16_t fwv;

  GetABFWversion(&fwc, &fwa, &fwv); 
  res = proto485OnlyWrite(0x09,fwc,fwa,fwv);
  printf("\n");
  printf("FW version is sent to Arduino!!!   ");
 }
 else
  {
  printf("Arrays have different elements.\n");
  }     

  /* 1st byte is the slave address byte which value should be >= RS485_ADDRESS_SLAVE_FIRST  &&
  <= RS485_ADDRESS_SLAVE_LAST and is already checked in dePadLeft() */
  for(int i = 1; i < length && buffer[i] >= RS485_PAYLOAD_VALID_MIN && buffer[i] <= RS485_PAYLOAD_VALID_MAX; i++);

  counter = i; // to be OK, i = length = RS485_MSG_LENGTH if response (after eventual dePad..) is OK
  printf("driver485Read %d\n",counter);


#ifdef RS485_DEBUG  
  static uint32_t i = 0;
  i++;
#endif

  return counter;

  GPIO_SetValue(PMAP_GPIO_PORT_DIR_RS485, PMAP_GPIO_PIN_DIR_RS485);  
}
```

file three.c:

```
uint8_t proto485OnlyWrite(uint8_t address, uint8_t command, uint8_t action, uint16_t value)               
{
  uint8_t res=ERROR_FOUND;

  OSSemPend(pbSemaphore, 0, &res);
  if (res == OS_ERR_NONE)
  {
    rs485_message_t rs485Msg;        
    if (command ==CMD_POWER_PUMP_PB)
    {
      printf("CMD_POWER_PUMP_PB");
    }

    proto485ComposeMsg(&rs485Msg, address, command, action, value);

    res = (RS485_MSG_LENGTH == driver485Write((uint8_t *)&rs485Msg, sizeof(rs485Msg))) ? 
  NO_ERROR: 
    ERROR_FOUND;

    OSSemPost(pbSemaphore);
  }    
  return res;
}
```

I want to get the values of "fwcommand", "fwaction" and "fwvalue" defined in file one.c into file two.c at the place where I am passing the same to "res = proto485OnlyWrite(0x09,fwc,fwa,fwv);" in the place of "fwc", "fwa" and "fwv" respectively.

Thank you....

Comment: Look up how to use header files. Define your functions with prototypes in the header files. Add "include" statements for the header files in the other files. This way the other files will "know" about the external references and you can access them.

Comment: Just put the function definitions you want to use at the top of one.c, e.g. `uint8_t proto485OnlyWrite(uint8_t address, uint8_t command, uint8_t action, uint16_t value);`.  Then you compile and link all three files together, e.g. `gcc -o myExe one.c two.c three.c`.

Comment: And what's the problem? You properly use pointers to extract the value from one function into another and then into third. Ignoring that you posted ton of unrelated code to your program that could be safely removed, you then pass the values into another function. All looks fine.

Comment: regarding: `return counter;  GPIO_SetValue( PMAP_GPIO_PORT_DIR_RS485, PMAP_GPIO_PIN_DIR_RS485);`   The call to `GPIO_SetValue()` will never be executed because the prior `return` statement has already exited the function
}`

Comment: @bruceg,  Your saying to make each of the (variables of interest -VOI-) have 'file scope'  That will not work.  Much better to have a header file that lists each of the -VOI- as 'extern' in a header file and `#include` that header file in any .c file that wants to access those -VOI-   However, then other files can also modify those -VOI-  So best is to write 'accessor' functions for those -VOI- and place the prototypes for those 'accessor' functions in the header file that anyone that wants to use those -VOI- includes in their file (cont)

Comment: (cont)  the last idea expressed ('accessor'' functions ) incorporates the concept of `data hiding` and `limiting the scope of a variable`  Both are very important concepts to adhere to when programming

Comment: @user3629249 I was just suggesting what I thought might be the easiest thing for the OP to do in order to get his code to compile. You are of course 100% correct.